# Removing html text between two tags with jsoup

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I would like to remove HTML text between two tags recursively like `<bloquotes>`

For this example:

```
<div>hfhfk
<bloquotes><bloquotes>ppppp</bloquotes>fin texte </bloquotes>
</div>
```

I'd like to have the following result:

```
<div>hfhfk</div>
```

Comment: And you want this done programatically? What programming languages can you use?

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you could do this:

```
$("bloquotes").each(function(){
       $(this).html("");
});
$("bloquotes").remove();
```

Comment: how can i do this with java and jsoup?

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
String html = "<div>hfhfk<bloquotes><bloquotes>ppppp</bloquotes>fin texte </bloquotes></div>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

Elements source = doc.select("div");
Element element = (Element) source.get(0);
Node result = element.childNode(0);
String nodeResult = result.toString().trim();

System.out.println(nodeResult + "");
System.out.println(nodeResult.length() + "");
```